# In Objective-C how to get NSDate with milliseconds? dateFromString: method is ignoring milliseconds

Tags: objective-c, date, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I have used following code:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
dateFormatter.timeZone = [NSTimeZone localTimeZone];
dateFormatter.locale = [NSLocale localeWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"];
dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'";
NSString *str = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'";
NSDate *dateToday =  [dateFormatter dateFromString:str];
```

Here value for str is correct with .milliseconds but when I try to convert this same string with same used datFormatter in NSDate, it returns NSdate without milliseconds.

Comment: `NSTimeInterval timeInSeconds = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970];`

Comment: OR `NSTimeInterval timeInSeconds = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970] * 1000;` these two can not helps you...?

Comment: @NiravKotecha I want Date - 2018-04-25T15:47:38.693. in this format,  Here .693 is milliseconds value. dateFromString is ignoring this & returning  - 2018-04-25T15:47:38

Comment: Converting NSTimeInterval also returning -  2049-04-25 10:24:05 +0000. i.e. without milliseconds

Comment: are you printing the description of NSDate?

Comment: How do you know converting back from the string representation loses the factional seconds? You don't show how you are testing this. Could it be that they way you are *viewing* the final date is omitting the fractional seconds?

Comment: NSLog the 'dateToday' value

Comment: Instead of using `NSLog` to check try comparing the before & after values using `NSDate` values, the `timeIntervalSince...` values, or by converting your final `NSDate` value to a string again and comparing the two strings. Do you still lose the fractional seconds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use these functions and try to log the dates to get the accurate results :-

```
-(NSString *)stringFromDate:(NSDate *)date{
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    dateFormatter.timeZone = [NSTimeZone localTimeZone];
    dateFormatter.locale = [NSLocale localeWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"];
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'";
    NSString *str = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
    NSLog(@"Date : %@",str);
    return str;
}

-(NSDate *)dateFromString:(NSString *)dateString{
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    dateFormatter.timeZone = [NSTimeZone localTimeZone];
    dateFormatter.locale = [NSLocale localeWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"];
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'";
    NSDate *date=[dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
    NSLog(@"Date : %@",[dateFormatter stringFromDate:date]);
    return date;
}
```

Comment: @ dreamBegin in your method - (NSDate *)dateFromString:  ,  NSLog(@"Date : %@",[dateFormatter stringFromDate:date]); prints correct string with milliseconds but   NSDate *date=[dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString]; does not, I don't want string with milliseconds , I want is NSDate with milliseconds

Comment: how do you know that your date doesn't have milliseconds?

Comment: NSLog the NSDate